# Get a random row in Cassandra using Datastax and CQL

Tags: groovy, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am NoSQL n00b, and just trying things out. I have the following keyspace with a single table in cassandra 2.0.2

```
CREATE KEYSPACE PersonDB WITH replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': '1'
 };

USE PersonDB;

CREATE TABLE Persons (
 id int,
 lastname text,
 firstname text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have close to 500 entries in the Persons table. I want to select any random row from the table. Is there an efficient way to do it in CQL? I am using groovy to invoke APIs exposed by datastax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to get "any" row you can just use `LIMIT`.

`select * from persons LIMIT 1;`

You would get the row with the lower hash of the partition key (id).

It will not be random, it will depend on your partitioner, but you would get A row.

Comment: Do you know what partitioner I should use to make this closer to random? Does the paritioner have to be specified at keyspace creation time? Whenever I use the query ``select * from persons LIMIT 1;" should I get a different row

Comment: Using the RandomPartitioner (default) you will get A row, but would it will be the same if the data does not change. If you really want to get a random row each time, you would have to create something custom solution (ie: another column family with the same partition key and use the person_id as clustering column)